# Does AVS API have scheduling features?

Tags: amazon-web-services, schedule, avspeechsynthesizer, avs

Does Amazon's AVS API have scheduling features, for example scheduling an audio player command? I need this for my Android application so I can make my code schedule the command and then the API actually playing back the audio on the Alexa device.

I tried looking for it but I don't know.